find -exec sh -c '...' script not honoring variables set in outer script
I am trying to write a shell script to check and delete files/folders
#!/bin/bash

deletepath="path"
donotdelete="$2"

timestamp=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)
filename=log_$timestamp.txt

logpath="logpath.txt"

find "$deletepath" -maxdepth 5 -exec sh -c '
for dir; do

    # Log the mtime and the directory name
    stat -c "%y %n" "$dir" >> "$logpath"

    if [ "$donotdelete" = "false" ]; then
        echo "deleting files"
    fi

done
' sh {} +

I am having problems with 2 lines
stat -c "%y %n" "$dir" >> "$logpath" 

For some reason $logpath is not replaced and it says permission error.
and if condition does not work and always deleting files is printed. Help would be much appreciated.

You need to export logpath for it to be visible in the subprocess. Same for donotdelete for that matter.

(btw, it's curious to use bash for the main script and sh for the child process -- is that a deliberate decision? I'd generally expect that you'd want to use the same interpreter for both for ease-of-development).

You mean use sh for script as well?

I mean, personally I tend to prefer to use bash everywhere, but you don't need it right now (unless you take Fravadona's suggestion, which makes use of bash-only features). But either way, picking one interpreter or the other and sticking to it makes more sense than using a different language variant for each part of your script.

@Hacker Can you provide a sample directory tree and show what you want to delete from it?

Single quotes suppress variable expansion.  Therefore your bash does not expand i.e. logpath, so the sh child process  sees $logpath, but never sets the variable. You have to place $logpath outside the single quotes, or put it into the environment, so that the variable is defined in the child process as well.

@user1934428, ..."put it into the environment" is by far the better practice: if you end the single quotes, substitute the data in the middle of a block of code and then resume the single-quoted context, that data is still parsed as code so one needs to worry about injection attacks (unless one uses printf %q, the bash 5+ ${var@Q} construct, or similar to perform eval-safe escaping).

As you're using bash you can optimize the code a litlle bit by not calling sh at all:
deletepath="path"
donotdelete="$2"

timestamp=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)
filename=log_$timestamp.txt

logpath="logpath.txt"

while IFS= read -r -d '' dir
do
    # Log the mtime and the directory name
    stat -c "%y %n" "$dir" >> "$logpath"

    if [ "$donotdelete" = "false" ]; then
        echo "deleting files"
    fi
done < <(find "$deletepath" -maxdepth 5 -print0)


If i am working on large filesystem. Which script would be faster. The one I am using or the one your suggested.?

This suggestion is unquestionably much faster if you have so many files that their names won't all fit on a single command line. (It may be faster even when that's not true as well, but if you switched from #!/bin/bash to #!/bin/sh for the shebang with the original then it could go either way -- depends on how much slower bash is than sh to start on your machine, if in fact it's slower at all -- whereas once find needs to start multiple copies of sh, getting rid of the child-process shells altogether is unambiguously a clear win).

Well, if you're using GNU find then you might be able to get rid of the for loop completely, which would be the fastest solution

Can you help with GNU find. I am very new to this.

GNU find has a -printf predicate which you can use to replace the stat command, and a -delete for deleting the files

Regarding the start times for the shell - that may well be distro dependent. On debian/ubuntu sh is a symlink to dash. On my desktop dash starts pretty much in  about half the time it takes bash, 0.003 vs 0.006.

Both your problems have the same cause: You aren't passing the variables logpath and donotdelete into the copy of sh that needs to use them.
Use export to copy shell variables into the environment, where they'll be available to subprocesses, or self-assign them at the beginning of the line as follows to temporarily export them only for the find command (and its subprocesses, thus also sh):
# ''var=value somecommand'' exports var only for the duration of somecommand
logpath="$logpath" donotdelete="$donotdelete" find "$deletepath" \
  -maxdepth 5 -exec sh -c '
for dir; do
    # Log the mtime and the directory name
    stat -c "%y %n" "$dir" >> "$logpath"

    if [ "$donotdelete" = "false" ]; then
        echo "deleting files"
    fi
done
' sh {} +


With GNU find:
delete=
if test "$2" = false; then
  delete=-delete
fi
find "$deletepath" -maxdepth 5 -printf '%T+ %TZ %p\n' >"$logpath" $delete


Is GNU much faster than above bash scripts suggested?

@Hacker yes, it should be

@oguzismail IMHO OP's requirements aren't clear enough yet; he's talking about directories but doesn't have the -type d predicate in his find command; he doesn't actually delete the files, just echoing something; the -maxdpeth 5 is also suspicious: what's the point of it when he'll end up deleting everything?

@Fravadona I agree that the question isn't clear enough

@Fravadona - My requirement is to delete files/folders with maxdepth of 5. I am just echoing for testing which will be replaced with delete statement.

My storage has 600TB+ of data with multiple layers of files. So using maxdepth to no go over all files/folders and clean up at somewhat top level.

@Hacker then you should consider adding a -mindepth predicate too

@Fravadona  Would that be necessary?
